# Why in GCC 4.4.1 I cannot declare default arguments in function template?

Tags: c++, gcc

1. In here:
   http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html
   They're saying that dflt tmp args in fnc are supported by their 4.4 ver. I run ver 4.4.1 and when I try to compile this:

d - guess what this d is here for? ;)

```
 #include<vector>

    template<class Key, class CollT = std::vector>
    CollT* delete_(Key kValue)
    {
        return new CollT;
    }

    int main()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

I'm getting an error.
So what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

std::vector is not a class it is a template. You can put in a syntax to indicate a template as a template parameter. In your case you might just want to make it `std::vector<Key>`

Comment: you may also want to replace: "template<class Key, class CollT = std::vector>" with "template<class Key, typename CollT = std::vector<Key> >

Comment: I've changed to what you've proposed and now I'm getting an error: 'CollT' was not declared in this scope|

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you shown was broken:
here is fix and how to build, and this works on g++ 4.4.5 so double check w/ your version:

```
#include<vector>
template <class Key, class CollT = std::vector<Key> >
CollT* delete_(Key kValue)
{
    return new CollT;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

to build:

g++ templdef.cpp -std=c++0x

EDITs based on comments:

```
   1) replace typename with class within template definition (both class CollT and typename CollT seems fine)
   2) replaced `vector<int>` with `vector<Key>`
   3) compiling without flag, will give you the following error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

Comment: You changed `class` to `typename`, and you included a template argument on `vector`; why would either of those changes require compiling against the C++0x standard instead of the default?

Comment: Default template parameters are not currently allowed in templated functions. They are in C++0x.